# Linear maps (find transformation matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

For any polinomial $p \in \mathscr P^2$ let $$q_p(t) := p(-1)+p(0)t + p(1)t^2 + p(2)t^3.$$

Consider the $\varphi\colon \mathscr P^2 \to \mathscr P^3$ defined by $\varphi(p) := q_p.$

Prove that the map $\varphi$ is linear and find its matrix in the pair of bases $\{1,t,t^2\}$ and $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}.$

---

As I was said $p(-1), p(0), p(1), p(2)$ are real numbers. But how to find them?

Comment: Why do you think you need to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also solve this "all in one go":

Suppose $p(t) = a + bt + ct^2 + dt^3$, then:

$p(-1) = a - b + c - d\\
p(0) = a\\
p(1) = a + b + c + d\\
p(2) = a + 2b  + 4c + 8d.$

Thus in the basis given, we have:

$\phi: \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}a-b+c-d\\a\\a+b+c+d\\a+2b+4c+8d\end{bmatrix}$

from which you can read off the rows of the matrix of $\phi$ in this basis (Don Antonio's answer uses particularly "nice" values for $a,b,c,d$ to make this easier).

Answer (score 1):

You can't find them as those values depend on the given polynomial $p$ , but you don't need them, either, to prove what you're asked.

Linearity is straighforward, for  example

$$\phi(p+q):=(p+q)(-1)+(p+q)(0)t+(p+q)(1)t+(p+q)(2)t^2=$$

$$=p(-1)+p(0)t+p(1)t^2+p(2)t^3+q(-1)+q(0)t+q(1)t^2+q(2)t^2=\phi p+\phi q$$

and etc.

For the matrix: apply $\;\phi\;$ on each of $\;\{1,t,t^2\}\;$ and write the outcome as linear combination of $\;\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}\;$ , and then take the transpose of the coefficients matrix. For example:

$$\phi(1)=1+t+t^2+t^3$$

$$\phi(t)=-1+0\cdot t+t+2t^2$$

and etc. thus, the first two **columns** of the matrix are the coefficients of the above lines, i.e.: first column (from the left) is $\;(1,1,1,1)\;$, and second column is $\;(-1,0,1,2)\;$. Now you continue on.